# android.text.Layout unresolved reference: getLineExtra

Tags: android, textview, span

Пишу свой Span, хочу получить line spacing сдвиг, чтобы правильно нарисовать символы. Использую метод:
android.text.Layout.getLineExtra. Android Studio пишет unresolved refernce. Импорт android.text.Layout есть. Метод getLineExtra public. В чем проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

У [android.text.Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/text/Layout) отсутствует метод `getLineExtra()`.

Comment: как это нет, если я захожу в исходники и он есть? Чет странное ваще происходит.

Comment: Вот так это нет. Для вас не исходники, а апи. Ссылку на апи я дал.

Comment: Это бред. Этот метод вызывается в BulletSpan. drawLeadingMargin https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/style/BulletSpan.java

Comment: Да и тут в исходниках он есть https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/Layout.java